# Can't Make Crosstab Query on a query containing SubQuery

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have query that contain subquery: to calculate the interval between departure and arrival time, from my table   "Timetable"

this Query works very fine, but when trying to execute it from the Crosstab, It prompts me an error that it cannot find table "a" which is alias I used for "Timetable"

```
SELECT a.VesselID, a.MovementID, a.MovementTime, (SELECT TOP 1 
 Timetable.MovementTime
 FROM Timetable
 WHERE (((Timetable.MovementID)="Arrival") AND 
 ((Timetable.VesselID)=a.VesselID]) AND ((Timetable.MovementTime)>a.
 [MovementTime]))
 ORDER BY Timetable.MovementTime) AS Arrival1,
DateDiff('h',[a].[MovementTime],[Arrival1]) AS [Interval]
FROM Timetable AS a INNER JOIN Timetable ON a.ID = Timetable.ID
WHERE (((a.MovementID)="Departure"));
```

I think this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890288/ms-access-crosstab-query-based-on-a-query-containing-a-subquery) is very similar, and the solution is that I split my query As @DHW said, but I couldn't do that.

and this is my try on splitting:

```
[Departure_Query]
    SELECT Timetable.VesselID, Timetable.MovementTime AS mymov, 
    Timetable.MovementID
    FROM Timetable
    WHERE (((Timetable.MovementID)="Departure"));

[Main]
    SELECT Timetable.MovementTime, Timetable.MovementID, Timetable.VesselID, Departure_Query.mymov, DateDiff('h',[mymov],[MovementTime]) AS [Interval]
    FROM Timetable INNER JOIN Departure_Query ON Timetable.VesselID = Departure_Query.VesselID
    WHERE (((Timetable.MovementTime)>[Departure_Query].[mymov]) AND ((Timetable.MovementID)="Arrival") AND ((Timetable.VesselID)=[Departure_Query].[VesselID]))
    ORDER BY Timetable.MovementTime;
```

I think the problem is:
In The working query I could put `SELECT TOP 1` but in the split try I dont know where to put it.

**update** Actually, right now i want to split it anyway, because when i am trying to build a report in top of it. It prompts me that Access cant do grouping on this field.

But anyway this my attempt

```
TRANSFORM DateDiff('h',[a].[MovementTime],[Arrival1]) AS [Interval]
SELECT a.MovementTime
FROM Timetable AS a INNER JOIN Timetable ON a.ID = Timetable.ID
WHERE (((a.MovementID)="Departure"))
GROUP BY a.MovementID, a.MovementTime, (SELECT TOP 1 Timetable.MovementTime
FROM Timetable
WHERE (((Timetable.MovementID)="Arrival") AND ((Timetable.VesselID)=a.[VesselID]) AND ((Timetable.MovementTime)>a.[MovementTime]))
ORDER BY Timetable.MovementTime)
PIVOT a.VesselID;
```

[The results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYqcM.png)[The Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4LgQ.png)

Comment: Post the attempted CROSSTAB. What field is the ColumnHeader? How many possible columns can result? Is this static or variable? There is a way to emulate CROSSTAB if static and not too many elements. http://www.datapigtechnologies.com/flashfiles/crosstab.html

Comment: I think it's dynamic, because it should show the working hours for each vessel per day. So it will grow with the length of the interval.  Actually, right now i want to split it anyway, because when i am trying to build a report in top of it. It prompts me that Access cant do grouping on this field.

Comment: Added the CROSSTAB attempt

Comment: Don't try to do it all in one SQL statement. Do the SELECT with the TOP 1 subquery and save that query object. Then build the CROSSTAB that refers to the first query object.

Comment: this what I am trying to do but unable to achieve, my "split query" I dont where to put `TOP 1`, If you can help I appreciate it

Comment: You build the SELECT with TOP 1 as posted in your question and save that as a query object. Then build the CROSSTAB as another query object that references the SELECT query object as source.

Comment: If you do what is suggested in the linked question, there is no TOP 1.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a crosstab with a domain aggregate, `DMin()` to replace subquery:

```
TRANSFORM DateDiff('h', main.[MovementTime], main.[Arrival1]) AS [Interval]
SELECT main.MovementID, main.MovementTime
FROM
   (SELECT t.VesselID, t.MovementID, t.MovementTime, 
           DMin("MovementTime", "Timetable", "MovementID = 'Arrival' 
                 AND VesselID = " & t.VesselID & " 
                 AND MovementTime > #" & t.MovementTime & "#") As Arrival1
    FROM Timetable AS t
    WHERE (((t.MovementID) = 'Departure'))
   ) As 
GROUP BY main.MovementID, main.MovementTime
PIVOT main.VesselID;
```

Comment: I am sorry, I don't think that I fully understand you.
I tried to apply your SQL statement but couldn't get it to work.
can you please elaborate on replacing by `Dmin()`.  


another thing: the only problem with my "Split Solution" is it compares all the later values than the departure time, The correct thing should be: It gets only the **first**  `ArrivalTime > DepartureTime` not all of them

  
thank you for you effort

Comment: *but couldn't get it to work*...what didn't work? Did you get an error? The `DMin()` should be the equivalent of the  `SELECT TOP 1` matching VesselID of outer query. This is a correlated query that returns one scalar for each row. I did not use your split solution but adjusted very first query.

Comment: I add a screenshot of the Query, kindly take alook

Comment: I am confused as the screenshot does not include my proposed `DMin()`. Please post a few rows of *Timetable* data and desired result of crosstab from those few rows. No screenshots.

Comment: Yes, domain aggregate function is option. Be aware any filter criteria applied to the query will have to be repeated in the function (such as date range).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Parfait and @June7, I am adding this answer so anyone in the future can benefit from this problem.

**The Problem**
I figured out the problem to be: The query is subtracting all the smaller departure dates for a specific Vessel
i.e. Vessel 1 Departed 6/1, 6/3, 6/6 and Arrived 6/2,6/2,6/8. so for the last day It was subtracting **6/8-6/6**, 6/8-6/3, 6/8-6/1. of the course the only first one (the bold one)is the right one.

**The Solution**

```
SELECT Min(Timetable.MovementTime) AS MinOfMovementTime, Departure_Query.mymov AS DeptDate, Min(DateDiff('h',[mymov],[MovementTime])) AS WorkingH, Timetable.MovementID, Timetable.VesselID
FROM Timetable LEFT JOIN Departure_Query ON Timetable.VesselID = Departure_Query.VesselID
WHERE (((Timetable.MovementID)="Arrival") AND ((Timetable.VesselID)=[Departure_Query].[VesselID]) AND ((Timetable.MovementTime)>[mymov]))
GROUP BY Departure_Query.mymov, Timetable.MovementID, Timetable.VesselID
ORDER BY Min(Timetable.MovementTime);
```

The only change here is `Min(DateDiff('h',[mymov],[MovementTime]))` which only give the smallest subtraction value, which translates to The biggest Departure Date.